# A word for a character trait that is of degrees?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some or maybe all character traits come in different degrees. For example some honest people are less/more honest than others. I want a word to describe such a feature.

Example:

That character trait is not the same in everyone who has it, but it is ---- .

I know of "of degrees", "subject to degrees", but I am looking for other words.

Comment: Gradable: capable of being graded. But this has far wider applications.

Answer (score 2):

I would say most (all?) character traits are ***qualitative***:

> Relating to, measuring, or measured by the quality of something rather than its quantity.
>   *‘a qualitative change in the undergraduate curriculum’*
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/qualitative)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I'd say something along the lines of **a spectrum** or **a continuum**. These clearly indicate that gradients exist.

Special usage note: *Spectrum* may have a modern connotation of being related to autism, as *on the spectrum* is a phrase I hear often to describe a person having autism without getting into further detail (i.e., *my niece is* ***on the spectrum***, more generic than saying something like *my niece has Asperger's*).